# React how to render single element which got multiple child element in different <td> in table row

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to React. I am having the following block of code which is returned and sent to a component to render in html table. Currently i am using something like below. is there a better way

```
bodyItems = sorted.map((data) => [
  data.employerName,
  data.sectors.map((sector) => <div>{sector.name}</div>),
  data.sectors.map((sector) => (
    <div>
      {sector.assignedLearners > 0
        ? `${sector.assignedLearners} learners`
        : 'Unassigned'}
    </div>
  )),
  data.lastModified
  ]
```

Rendering as:

```
bodyItems.map((entry, rowIndex) => (
    <tr key={rowIndex}>
      {entry.map((cell, colIndex) => (
        <td key={colIndex}>{cell}</td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  ))
```

Can anyone help how to render each div of the sectors in a separate  in the component.

Expected output:

```
<tr>
  <td>Employer Name</td>
  <td>
    <div>Sector 1</div>
    <div>Sector 2</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>20 Learners</div>
    <div>10 learners</div>
   </td>
  <td>
  <!-- ... additional properties-->
  </td>
</tr>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to render each fragment you mapped from `data.sectors` into its own `<td>`? So you get a table structure like this?

```html
<tr>
  <td>Employer Name</td>
  <td>
    <div>Sector 1</div>
    <div>2 learners</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>Sector 2</div>
    <div>Unknown</div>
  </td>
  <!-- ... additional sectors -->
</tr>
```

If so, you need to flatten the array created with `data.sectors.map`, so you don't end up with a nested array. You can accomplish that with the spread operator (`...`) assuming your project supports it.

```
bodyItems = sorted.map((data) => [
  data.employerName,
  ...data.sectors.map((sector) => (
    <>
      <div>{sector.name}</div>
      <div>
        {sector.assignedLearners > 0
          ? `${sector.assignedLearners} learners`
          : 'Unassigned'}
      </div>
    </>
  ))
])
```

Alternatively, you could use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

```
bodyItems = sorted.flatMap((data) => [
  data.employerName,
  data.sectors.map((sector) => (
    <>
      <div>{sector.name}</div>
      <div>
        {sector.assignedLearners > 0
          ? `${sector.assignedLearners} learners`
          : 'Unassigned'}
      </div>
    </>
  ))
])
```